# PhpMailer Internal Server error

Tags: php, phpmailer

Tinha essa função rodando no localhost perfeitamente, e em todos os testes ela enviava os email's corretamente mas depois que coloquei no meu servidor ela não envia mais os email's e dá o erro "500 Internal Server error" alguém sabe qual o problema? obrigado

```
function SendMail($subject, $message, $to, $toName){

$mail = new PHPMailer();

// Servidor
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host       = 'xxxxxxxxx';
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->Username   = 'xxxxxxx';
$mail->Password   = 'xxxxxx';
$mail->Port       = xxxx;
$mail->SMTPSecure = false;

// Remetente
$mail->From       = 'xxxxx';
$mail->FromName   = 'xxxx';

// Destino
$mail->addAddress($to, $toName);

// Dados da Messagem
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->CharSet    = 'utf-8';
$mail->WordWrap   = 70;

// Mensagem
$mail->Subject    = $subject;
$mail->Body       = $message;
$mail->Altbody    = strip_tags($message);

return $mail->Send();
}
```

Obs: xxx= são os meu dados pessoais que não coloquei aqui mas estão corretos no meu servidor.

Comment: Você sabe se o envio de emails está habilitado no servidor remoto? Você tem acesso aos logs da aplicação?

Comment: sim estão habilitas, está tudo certo, antes eu utilizava as mesmas configurações de envio de email no meu servidor remoto para o localhost e os email eram enviados, depois que subi os arquivos para o servidor já não dá.

Comment: O que mudou de antes para depois?

Comment: em relação ao código ou resposta do servidor? O código está igual porque as configurações de envio de email do meu servidor remoto são as mesmas

Comment: Adicione essas duas linha no inicio do arquivo que chama a sua função, `ini_set('display_errors', true);error_reporting(E_ALL);` se tiver algum erro ele vai hablitar a exibição. Coloque tbm o debug do phpmailer, `$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;`

Comment: não modificou nada... a página carrega cerca de 30 segundos e depois exibe a mensagem "Internal Server Error"

Comment: Agora ele retornou o erro "SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110) 2015-01-08 17:17:12 SMTP connect() failed."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

estive utilizando o phpmailer há pouco tempo e sofri o mesmo problema que o teu, tenho duas dicas para te passar:

1° verifique se o modulo do php openssl esta habilitado, o phpmailer precisa dele

2° se for Gmail,Hotmail,Yahoo utilize a porta 587.